# how to save networkx to shape file?

Tags: networkx

I have searched around but still didn't find a proper tutorial about the networkx `write_shp()`. Currently I have the graph variable `G` and nodes position dictionary `pos`.

According to the [document](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.write_shp.html), the nodes and edges have to have the 'Wkb' or 'Wkt'. How could I assign this 'Wkb' to my current graph? Currently, the error pops up saying.

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I hope to draw the map by arcgis after obtaining this shape file. Also, I hope the shape file could preserve the edges attributes if possible.

Answer (score 0):

1)Replace the node name with the node coordinate.

2)Set the node and edge attributes as either int, float, or string. Tuple is not supported.

3)See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754277/networkx-writing-to-shape-file/68778945#68778945).